# Storing a large encrypted string in a database

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

So in terms of best practice to store a pretty large encrypted string of data in mysql, is there a certain way that i should be storing a string that is this length?

```
9tjIxIzNwgDMwIjI6gjOztjIlRXYkt2Ylh2YioTO6M3OicmbpNnblNWasx1cyVmdyV2ccNXZsVHZv1GX
zNWbodHXlNmc192czNWbodHXzN2bkRHacBFUNFEWcNHduVWb1N2bExFd0FWTcNnclNXVcpzQioDM4ozc
7ISey9GdjVmcpRGZpxWY2JiO0EjOztjIx4CMuAjL3ITMioTO6M3OiAXaklGbhZnI6cjOztjI0N3boxWY
j9Gbuc3d3xCdz9GasF2YvxmI6MjM6M3Oi4Wah12bkRWasFmdioTMxozc7ISeshGdu9WTiozN6M3OiUGb
jl3Yn5WasxWaiJiOyEjOztjI3ATL4ATL4ADMyIiOwEjOztjIlRXYkVWdkRHel5mI6ETM6M3OicDMtcDM
tgDMwIjI6ATM6M3OiUGdhR2ZlJnI6cjOztjIlNXYlxEI5xGa052bNByUD1ESXJiO5EjOztjIl1WYuR3Y
1R2byBnI6ETM6M3OicjI6EjOztjIklGdjVHZvJHcioTO6M3Oi02bj5ycj1Ga3BEd0FWbioDNxozc7ICb
pFWblJiO1ozc7IyUD1ESXBCd0FWTioDMxozc7ISZtFmbkVmclR3cpdWZyJiO0EjOztjIlZXa0NWQiojN
6M3OiMXd0FGdzJiO2ozc7pjMxoTY8baca0885830a33725148e94e693f3f073294c0558d38e31f844
c5e399e3c16a
```

Comment: what you want to do with this string. if the string in any where condition in a query or only in the field list ?

Comment: Its the WHMCS licensing system. You would just be retrieving the string.There would be no clauses involving the string itself.You have to store that local key.It then checks that encrypted string against a stored license key with a PHP function.

Comment: in this case you can use the datatype **BINARY**, **CHAR BYTE**, or **VARBINARY** for non fixed length. here the manual page : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/string-data-types/

Comment: Thanks allot, will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your purpose is with this string. If you intend to fetch this string and decrypt at your application end then you can store them as with any other large string value by making the column as [The BLOB or TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html)

I believe you don't intend to use this string data in your query

Comment: You are correct in that assumption, i would just be retrieving it and checking it against a stored license key.